# Parsing array to string and back in Flutter

Tags: arrays, string, parsing, flutter, dart

Let me start with the background of the problem. I converted my 2-dimensional array into String in Python because of API requirements and now I need to parse it back to array in my Flutter app.
I can't seem to find an eligible solution to this problem. I am familiar with the method in Python called **ast.literal_eval**, so I was wondering if there is maybe an alternative for it in Flutter. Thank You very much for your help.

Comment: whats wrong with [json](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json)?

Comment: Less data is being transferred this way, which is very important for this project.

Comment: Elements are mostly strings and integers.

Comment: @FilipJurković what do you mean by less data is being transferred when used JSON ?

Comment: @FilipJurković and how your array elements are separated when you are converting array to string, whitespace or something else to separate each array item ?

Comment: Can you give an example of one of those strings in your questions? Elements are "mostly" ints and strings, so it can be other data types as well? Can the types of elements be mixed?